# Equals in C# using directive

Tags: c#

I've seen this once or twice and don't have the foggiest idea what it's for:

```
using Point = This.Namespace.Thing.Point
```

In a couple of examples online I've seen this sort of syntax along with the rest of the usual using directives one is used to seeing.  What's this all about?

Comment: It's a type or namespace alias. Basically you just create an abbreviation for This.Namespace.Thing.Point called Point.

Comment: Just have a look at the docs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: If you Google this exact question title, you'll find a detailed article about C# aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a shorthand notation or alias for `Namespace`.

you can use it to avoid typing lengthy namespaces.

```
using Point = This.Namespace.Thing.Point;
```

if you write as above then

```
This.Namespace.Thing.Point.anyClassName
```

is Equals to

```
Point.anyClassName
```

Comment: So what's the purpose of including an alias for a namespace? I guess if you have to different namespaces with the class Point?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: you are absolutly right , either you can use it to avoid typing lengthy namespace or to avoid ambiguity between two different namespaces

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, in my experience, the use of the `using` directive as an alias is for one of three things - either to change the spelling of a type in a namespace you do not control, to use a shorter version of a long class name, or to give a more meaningful name to a generic type (e.g., `NamePair` instead of `Tuple<String, String>`).